# C# EF LocalDB Not Working in Different Computer

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple WPF app using EF 6.1.3 with a File/localDb that resides inside the Solution/Project Folder. In the computer where  VS is installed everything works fine.

I went to a different computer installed .NET and SqlLocalDB (SQL Express 2012).
I ran the Exe in the remote computer everything works fine except the connection to the Db. Could this be a Connection String issue under the config file? Or Am I missing something?

My Connection String under config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ManagerEntities" 
       connectionString="metadata=res://*/StoreModel.csdl|res://*/StoreModel.ssdl|res://*/StoreModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Manager.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
       providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Thank you

Comment: is this your actual connection string ? "=|DataDirectory|\Manager.mdf"

Comment: Try checking the name of the SQL Express instance running, it my be different from the one in the connection string.

Comment: My mdf is under the application directory that s why I m using "=|DataDirectory|\Manager.mdf". I`m using SqlLocalDb, I don`t see any service associated with, I should have one?

Comment: Shouldn`t the EF mount the mdf automatically when the app starts? I m using the cmd line SqlLocalDb and I don`t see any mounted instance...

Comment: 2h later I decided to reboot the computer, now it s working, thank you all.